# Ternary operator logic not working for boolean, evaluating to false when it's not false

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator, ternary

I'm mapping a little block of project objects for a set of footer links and I want each project name to be followed by a | EXCEPT the last one. Here's the code.

```
const projects = [
  {
    lastOne: false,
    project: "Kuma",
    link: "",
    image: "./kuma.png",
  },
  {
    lastOne: false,
    project: "Rin Starseed",
    link: "",
    image: "./star.png",
  },
  {
    lastOne: true,
    project: "Sea Harvest",
    link: "",
    image: "./fish.png",
  },
];
```

Then the logic in the footer component

```
function ProjectLinks({ link, project, lastOne }) {
  return (
    <a href={link} target="_blank" style={{ color: "white" }}>
      {lastOne ? project + " | " : project}
    </a>
  );
}
```

It evaluates to false, only lists the project names no |

Comment: Please show us how you call ProjectLInks from the loop.

Comment: your condition is the wrong way around, currently you're saying that **only** the last one should have a `|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is the wrong way around, it should be:

```
{lastOne ? project : (project + " | ")}
```

---

You're probably not passing the props to `ProjectLinks` whereby `lastOne` is a falsy value and so the `|` isn't shown.

You could spread the complete object to pass all the props:

```
{projects.map(p => <ProjectLinks {...p} /> )}
```

###### *Demo*:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const projects = [
        {lastOne: false, project: "Kuma", link: "", image: "./kuma.png", },
        {lastOne: false, project: "Rin Starseed", link: "", image: "./star.png", },
        {lastOne: true, project: "Sea Harvest", link: "", image: "./fish.png", },
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            {projects.map(p => <ProjectLinks {...p} /> )}
        </div>
    )
}

function ProjectLinks({ link, project, lastOne }) {
    return (
        <a href={link} target="_blank" style={{ color: "red" }}>
            {lastOne ? project : project + " | "}
        </a>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

But this is not really scalable, since you'll need to loop over the items in the projects array, you can use the iterator of the loop (`map()` in the examples) to check if that is the last item in the list:

```
{projects.map((p, i) => <ProjectLinks {...p} lastOne={i === projects.length - 1} /> )}
```

###### *Demo*:

```js
const Example = () => {

    const projects = [
        { project: "Kuma", link: "", image: "./kuma.png", },
        { project: "Rin Starseed", link: "", image: "./star.png", },
        { project: "Sea Harvest", link: "", image: "./fish.png", },
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            {projects.map((p, i) => <ProjectLinks {...p} lastOne={i === projects.length - 1} /> )}
        </div>
    )
}

function ProjectLinks({ link, project, lastOne }) {
    return (
        <a href={link} target="_blank" style={{ color: "red" }}>
            {lastOne ? project : project + " | "}
        </a>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Gotcha. Swapping the sides displays the | but it's still not pulling the bar from the end of the false object. Edit: Oh wait no you're right. I didn't add the prop!